# What is the picker pattern used in the iphone calendar app? NOT a UIPickerView question

Tags: iphone

Sorry another newbie question that I couldn't seem to find an answer to on google. Guess I don't know how to describe it well enough.

On the calendar app for the iphone, when you go to add an event, if you select from the repeat, invitees, alert sections and so forth, you are brought to a screen with some choices for the field.

Is this simply navigating to a new view controller on the tap which displays these choices, or is there an pattern that you can implement for this out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a garden-variety UITableViewController that's pushed onto the navigation controller's stack.

It's probably passed either a reference to the event object or a delegate it can send a message to to set the selected value when "Done" is tapped.

Comment: That's what I figured. Is the UITableViewCell a custom one to display the label and the value?

Comment: Try UITableViewCellStyleValue1. It wouldn't surprise me if they've done something custom though.